# Conversion of OR logical operator from C++ to Fortran

Tags: c++, if-statement, fortran, logical-operators, or-operator

What would be the conversion of following C++ logical operator into Fortran 90 (.f90)? If (`vx` is present or `vy` is present). Here `vx` and `vy` are components of velocity

```
if(vx || vy){
vT=sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy);
}
```

I have tried following

```
if(vx .or. vy) then
vT = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)
end if
```

but I am getting error:

```
operands of logical operator `.or.` at (1) are REAL(8)/REAL(8).
```

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: Depending on the types of `vx` and `vy`, the C++ expression `vx || vy` is equivalent to `vx != 0 || vy != 0`. Maybe that equivalence might help?

Answer (score 7):

The C++ version is implicitly comparing `vx` and `vy` with zero.

In Fortran, you have to do so explicitly<sup>1</sup>:

```
if (vx /= 0 .or. vy /= 0) then
```

Since the `if` statement looks like a performance optimization, it might be worth questioning whether it's needed altogether or could be replaced with an unconditional assignment to `vT` (that would set `vT` to zero if both `vx` and `vy` are zero).

<sup>1</sup> I hope I got this right; haven't programmed in Fortran for many years.

Comment: Judging by the case used in your answer, you've programmed in Fortran since I have, and this looks correct to me. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I agree, the case does look... wrong. :) I only used it for consistency with the question.

Comment: I used FORTRAN 77 at University but luckily managed to use C in my postgraduate. In think the case requirements, along with the necessity of typing 6 spaces on every line, were relaxed in Fortran 90.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Oh, the spaces, I completely forgot about the spaces! :) [I did some Fortran for my PhD and then briefly at a financial institution that shall remain nameless but was rumoured to have upwards of 10 million lines of Fortran code.]

Comment: @Bathesba The spaces are irrelevant in free format files which typically have the .f90 extension (which I understand from the question the OP wants).

Answer (score 4):

In the present case it is not relevant, but in general it should be noted that Fortran logical operations are not short-circuited. So, for example, the following C++ code

```
if (a == 0 || 10 / a == 1)
{
   ...
}
```

is not equivalent to

```
if (a == 0 .or. 10 / a == 1) then
    ...
end if
```

in Fortran. A compiler may decide to evaluate the second term first and then... oops. It should be written using two nested `if`s.

Comment: [Section 7.1.7 of the standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) states: _It is not necessary for a processor to evaluate all of the operands of an expression, or to evaluate entirely each operand if the value of the expression can be determined otherwise._ An example they use is `X>Y .OR. L(Z)` where they say _the function reference `L(Z)` need not be
evaluated if `X` is greater than `Y`_ So yes, this seems to be processor dependent or is my conclusion wrong here?

Comment: @kvantour, it is up to compiler to decide how to evaluate a logical expression in each particular situation - evaluation order is compiler-dependent and expression-dependent. This freedom gives more space for possible code optimizations.

Comment: But there is an extra interesting fact: _In the examples (`X>Y .OR. L(Z)`),  if `L` defines its argument `Z`, evaluation of the expressions under the specified conditions causes `Z` to become undefined, no matter whether or not `L(Z)` is evaluated._ So that is something to think about.

Comment: @kvantour, this seems to be a natural addendum to 7.1.7/1, though not trivial.

Comment: Yes, I just copied pasted it. But I was baffled If you have a function like `L(Z)` that sets `Z=1.0` and returns  `L=.true.`, it would not set `Z` to `1.0` as it becomes undefined. Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @kvantour, take a look at 2.4.4/1: *When a variable does not have a predictable value, it is undefined*. I've written a small program to check the value of `Z` after the condition `L(Z)` is evaluated. With `gfortran`, if `L(Z)` is evaluated, `Z` is set, as expected. My guess (I'm far from being a Fortran expert) is that using `Z` after `X>Y .OR. L(Z)` is something like UB in C++ - a compiler can do whatever it wants, though in many cases UB has predictable (but not reliable) consequences.